# Bash: replace list of numbers in column with sequential list

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I need to replace the first column of numbers with a list of sequential numbers.  The file looks like:

```
 1     the   quick   brown     fox   jumps    over  
 7     the    lazy     dog     the   quick   brown
13     fox   jumps    over     the    lazy     dog
26     the   quick   brown     fox   jumps    over
31     the    lazy     dog     the   quick   brown
```

and I need:

```
 1     the   quick   brown     fox   jumps    over  
 2     the    lazy     dog     the   quick   brown
 3     fox   jumps    over     the    lazy     dog
 4     the   quick   brown     fox   jumps    over
 5     the    lazy     dog     the   quick   brown
```

Any solutions with bash/sed/awk would be appreciated.

Comment: Sed is not best tools for this due to lake of internal treament other than replace pattern by other (no count, ...). Possible but very heavy compare to awk with a simple command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `awk`

```
awk '$1=NR' OFS="\t" file
1       the     quick   brown   fox     jumps   over
2       the     lazy    dog     the     quick   brown
3       fox     jumps   over    the     lazy    dog
4       the     quick   brown   fox     jumps   over
5       the     lazy    dog     the     quick   brown
```

Since `NR` is always a number larger than `0` this will always be true and printed.
You could use `'{$1=NR}1` or `{$1=NR;print $0}` to make it more readable.

Comment: Wow yours is better man..I did not know we could simply write it this way. \m/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the awk variable `NR` which gives you the record number being processed.
If you want asample code see below:
Suppose the file has records like this

```
1 ask
5 rup
6 dd
```

Now run this below command:

```
 awk '{ print NR FS $2 }' filename
```

Output:

```
1 ask
2 rup
3 dd
```

Rest i leave on you to figure out